# time data does not match format ... even though it does

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am new to Python and programming and would appreciate help on a small problem! I have a CSV file with three columns of data that I would like to plot: the first, with dates, I would like to plot as my x-axis; the second and third columns hold data corresponding to those dates.

I would like to plot these data. I have written a script that should read the CSV file, convert the dates column values from string data to timestamps, and then plot values from the other columns against timestamps to make a timeseries.

When I try to run the script, it returns the error message:

" ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%d/%m/%y' ".

However, when opening my CSV file, all date values are stored in the format e.g. 31/01/16, which seems to match the format I have specified in Python.

I share my script below for any possible help. Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import style
style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.read_csv('Fuego_mirova_vs_rsam.csv', delimiter=',')
np.shape(df)

dates=['Date']
vrp=['VRP (Watt)']
rsam=['rsam']

for indexr, row in df.iterrows():
    dates.append(row.values[0])
    vrp.append(row.values[1])
    rsam.append(row.values[2])

FMT = '%d/%m/%y'
dtlist = []

for i in range(0, len(dates)):
    dtlist.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(dates[i], FMT))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10))

ax.plot(dtlist, vrp, label='Radiative power [W]')
ax.plot(dtlist, rsam, label='Average daily seismic amplitude')

plt.legend
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are string to parse the actual string `Date` as a date.

Comment: on a side-note: matplotlib can use `pandas.Series`, so you can just do `ax.plot(df[<x-label>], df[<y-label>]`; and instead of using `for i in range(len(list)): do_something_with(list[i])` you can use `for i in list: do_something_with(i)`. If you want to apply a function on a whole `Series` in a `DataFrame`, you can use [apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the entire `date` column into `datetime` objects with

```
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
```

that way you don't need the call to `strptime` at all, `pandas` should be able to figure out what the date format is

Comment: That sounds very efficient. I've tried implementing it in my code but it returns the error "KeyError: 0". It seems pandas is trying to convert strings to datetimes in a list that doesn't yet exist?

Comment: `0` is referring to the column names in `pd.to_datetime(df[0])` - pandas in complaining that it cannot find a column named `0` in the `df`. You need to replace `0` with whatever your first column is called

Answer (score 1):

You have the string value of `'Date'` in your column that is throwing the error.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """Date,value
31/01/16,1
31/01/16,1
Date,1
31/01/16,1
31/01/16,1"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt))
df

       Date  value
0  31/01/16      1
1  31/01/16      1
2      Date      1
3  31/01/16      1
4  31/01/16      1
```

If I attempt the convert this to `Timestamp`

```
df.Data = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%y')
```

> ```
> ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%d/%m/%y' (match)
> ```

You can either fix your data or you can convert that to `NaT` (Not a Time[stamp]) with the `errors` parameter

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%y', errors='coerce')
df

        Date  value
0 2016-01-31      1
1 2016-01-31      1
2        NaT      1
3 2016-01-31      1
4 2016-01-31      1
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly it. Good to know!